# High ram usage is slowing down my laptop

Tags: ram, memory-usage

Generally when I boot up my laptop and open firefox and other softwares, it used to consume nearly 1 gb of ram. my laptop 4 gb ram. But today suddenly after booting up, htop showed me that without the firefox being opened my ram usage is 3.13 gb out of 3.77 gb. When I ran [ps_mem.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py) 
the output was:

```
 4.0 KiB +  14.5 KiB =  18.5 KiB   bamfdaemon-dbus
 4.0 KiB +  16.5 KiB =  20.5 KiB   avahi-dnsconfd
 4.0 KiB +  17.5 KiB =  21.5 KiB   agetty
 4.0 KiB +  20.5 KiB =  24.5 KiB   dbus-launch
 4.0 KiB +  31.5 KiB =  35.5 KiB   bluetoothd
 4.0 KiB +  33.5 KiB =  37.5 KiB   dbus
 4.0 KiB +  36.5 KiB =  40.5 KiB   gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
 4.0 KiB +  36.5 KiB =  40.5 KiB   gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
 4.0 KiB +  38.5 KiB =  42.5 KiB   cupsd
 4.0 KiB +  40.5 KiB =  44.5 KiB   ibus-dconf
 4.0 KiB +  40.5 KiB =  44.5 KiB   gvfsd-network
 4.0 KiB +  41.5 KiB =  45.5 KiB   gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
 4.0 KiB +  42.5 KiB =  46.5 KiB   deja-dup-monitor
48.0 KiB +  19.5 KiB =  67.5 KiB   atd
52.0 KiB +  17.5 KiB =  69.5 KiB   acpid
68.0 KiB +   4.5 KiB =  72.5 KiB   ssh-agent
 4.0 KiB +  70.5 KiB =  74.5 KiB   obexd
 4.0 KiB +  71.5 KiB =  75.5 KiB   gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
96.0 KiB +  20.5 KiB = 116.5 KiB   systemd-udevd
 4.0 KiB + 117.5 KiB = 121.5 KiB   whoopsie
112.0 KiB +  24.5 KiB = 136.5 KiB   cron
132.0 KiB +  25.5 KiB = 157.5 KiB   syndaemon
116.0 KiB +  42.5 KiB = 158.5 KiB   at-spi-bus-launcher
 4.0 KiB + 158.5 KiB = 162.5 KiB   gjs-console
160.0 KiB +  17.5 KiB = 177.5 KiB   irqbalance
164.0 KiB +  28.5 KiB = 192.5 KiB   rtkit-daemon
148.0 KiB +  52.5 KiB = 200.5 KiB   gnome-pty-helper
128.0 KiB +  82.5 KiB = 210.5 KiB   gvfsd-dnssd
128.0 KiB +  87.5 KiB = 215.5 KiB   cups-browsed
220.0 KiB +  31.5 KiB = 251.5 KiB   dnsmasq
 4.0 KiB + 254.5 KiB = 258.5 KiB   unattended-upgr
244.0 KiB +  66.0 KiB = 310.0 KiB   avahi-daemon (2)
268.0 KiB +  55.5 KiB = 323.5 KiB   speech-dispatcher
320.0 KiB +  37.5 KiB = 357.5 KiB   gnome-keyring-daemon
348.0 KiB +  53.5 KiB = 401.5 KiB   gvfsd-fuse
400.0 KiB +  20.5 KiB = 420.5 KiB   systemd-logind
372.0 KiB +  54.5 KiB = 426.5 KiB   at-spi2-registryd
380.0 KiB +  64.5 KiB = 444.5 KiB   gvfsd
384.0 KiB +  65.5 KiB = 449.5 KiB   ibus-engine-simple
356.0 KiB + 104.5 KiB = 460.5 KiB   thermald
460.0 KiB +  21.5 KiB = 481.5 KiB   rsyslogd
424.0 KiB +  71.5 KiB = 495.5 KiB   gvfsd-trash
368.0 KiB + 146.5 KiB = 514.5 KiB   mate-screensaver
488.0 KiB + 141.5 KiB = 629.5 KiB   polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1
452.0 KiB + 218.5 KiB = 670.5 KiB   ibus-x11
588.0 KiB + 122.5 KiB = 710.5 KiB   upowerd
660.0 KiB +  57.5 KiB = 717.5 KiB   accounts-daemon
668.0 KiB +  51.5 KiB = 719.5 KiB   wpa_supplicant
808.0 KiB +  41.5 KiB = 849.5 KiB   ntpd
688.0 KiB + 167.5 KiB = 855.5 KiB   sd_generic
688.0 KiB + 168.5 KiB = 856.5 KiB   sd_cicero
692.0 KiB + 166.5 KiB = 858.5 KiB   sd_dummy
812.0 KiB +  88.0 KiB = 900.0 KiB   lightdm (2)
912.0 KiB +  15.5 KiB = 927.5 KiB   dhclient
568.0 KiB + 414.5 KiB = 982.5 KiB   blueman-applet
888.0 KiB +  97.5 KiB = 985.5 KiB   gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
960.0 KiB +  35.5 KiB = 995.5 KiB   dconf-service
872.0 KiB + 162.5 KiB =   1.0 MiB   mate-session
940.0 KiB + 131.5 KiB =   1.0 MiB   udisksd
992.0 KiB + 219.5 KiB =   1.2 MiB   applet.py
 1.3 MiB +  25.5 KiB =   1.4 MiB   systemd-journald
 1.1 MiB + 327.5 KiB =   1.4 MiB   notification-area-applet
 1.3 MiB + 180.5 KiB =   1.5 MiB   sudo
 1.2 MiB + 343.5 KiB =   1.6 MiB   mate-volume-control-applet
 1.4 MiB + 274.5 KiB =   1.7 MiB   sd_espeak
 1.8 MiB + 238.5 KiB =   2.0 MiB   mate-maximus
 1.7 MiB + 290.5 KiB =   2.0 MiB   mate-power-manager
 1.7 MiB + 440.5 KiB =   2.2 MiB   clock-applet
 2.1 MiB + 107.5 KiB =   2.2 MiB   ibus-daemon
 2.1 MiB + 136.5 KiB =   2.3 MiB   systemd (3)
 2.2 MiB +  50.5 KiB =   2.3 MiB   polkitd
 1.2 MiB +   1.3 MiB =   2.5 MiB   postgres (6)
 2.5 MiB + 240.5 KiB =   2.7 MiB   dbus-daemon (3)
 2.3 MiB + 377.5 KiB =   2.7 MiB   tilda
 2.6 MiB + 429.5 KiB =   3.0 MiB   mate-settings-daemon
 2.8 MiB + 312.5 KiB =   3.1 MiB   ibus-ui-gtk3
 2.7 MiB + 608.5 KiB =   3.3 MiB   update-notifier
 3.3 MiB + 187.5 KiB =   3.5 MiB   NetworkManager
 3.5 MiB + 323.5 KiB =   3.8 MiB   pulseaudio
 4.1 MiB +  45.5 KiB =   4.2 MiB   gvfsd-metadata
 3.6 MiB + 932.5 KiB =   4.5 MiB   mate-panel
 4.2 MiB + 564.5 KiB =   4.7 MiB   bamfdaemon
 4.8 MiB + 123.0 KiB =   4.9 MiB   bash (2)
 4.3 MiB +   1.1 MiB =   5.4 MiB   marco
 5.9 MiB +  10.5 KiB =   5.9 MiB   snapd
 5.3 MiB + 873.5 KiB =   6.1 MiB   nm-applet
 6.2 MiB +   1.2 MiB =   7.5 MiB   plank
 8.5 MiB +   2.2 MiB =  10.8 MiB   mate-terminal
16.8 MiB +   3.6 MiB =  20.4 MiB   Xorg
25.1 MiB +   1.4 MiB =  26.5 MiB   caja
747.4 MiB +  85.4 MiB = 832.8 MiB   firefox (7)
---------------------------------
                         1.0 GiB
=================================
```

and `free -h` is giving the following result :

```
Mem:           3.8G        3.2G        148M         76M        448M        240M
Swap:          975M        368M        607M
```

And `top` output is :

```
top - 19:57:56 up 52 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.88, 0.88, 0.96
Tasks: 191 total,   1 running, 139 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.8 us,  1.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.4 id,  1.7 wa,  0.2 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3948976 total,   167676 free,  3356364 used,   424936 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   999420 total,   689352 free,   310068 used.   239448 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2411 rakib      1   0 3391600 456092 109600 S   0.0 11.5   4:30.21 firefox
 3962 rakib      1   0 2682112 176984 122216 S   0.0  4.5   0:35.00 Web Content
 2475 rakib      1   0 2773772 167840  72108 S   0.0  4.3   1:30.76 Web Content
 2558 rakib      1   0 2660024 127660  59076 S   0.0  3.2   0:09.10 WebExtensions
 3310 rakib      1   0 2677744 119648  77552 S   0.0  3.0   0:42.19 Web Content
 3917 rakib      1   0 2585732 108020  84524 S   0.0  2.7   0:01.85 Web Content
 3999 rakib      1   0 2570348  82192  62632 S   0.0  2.1   0:00.37 Web Content
 1116 root       1   0  304372  32704  22352 S   0.0  0.8   1:11.99 Xorg
 4052 rakib      1   0  628488  30988  24372 S   0.0  0.8   0:01.50 mate-terminal
 1779 rakib      1   0  593436  26156  20724 S   0.0  0.7   0:02.44 plank
 1756 rakib      1   0 1251488  22692  16648 S   0.0  0.6   0:04.16 caja
 1816 rakib      1   0  596564  21288  16576 S   0.0  0.5   0:02.33 nm-applet
 1877 rakib      1   0  470792  17884  15060 S   0.0  0.5   0:11.35 marco
 1748 rakib      1   0 1172888  16848  13544 S   0.0  0.4   0:01.43 mate-settings-d
 1711 rakib      1   0  480480  16144  13632 S   0.0  0.4   0:01.63 ibus-ui-gtk3
 1899 rakib      1   0  449576  16044  11756 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.97 bamfdaemon
 1825 rakib      1   0  589348  15992  14804 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.81 tilda
 1960 rakib      1   0  616724  15920  14312 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.43 clock-applet
 1752 rakib      1   0  629860  15636  13584 S   0.0  0.4   0:01.19 mate-panel
 1764 rakib      1   0  629856  15492  14628 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.91 blueman-applet
 1790 rakib      1   0  550712  14932  13808 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.36 mate-volume-con
 1767 rakib      1   0  571448  14632  13944 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.49 update-notifier
 1784 rakib      1   0  469096  10572   9712 S   0.0  0.3   0:00.45 mate-power-mana
 1715 rakib      1   0  353048  10344  10004 S   0.0  0.3   0:00.24 ibus-x11
  960 root       1   0  450504   9912   7876 S   0.0  0.3   0:02.95 NetworkManager
 1826 rakib      1   0  404964   9068   7952 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.37 mate-maximus
 1962 rakib      1   0  398380   8880   8072 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.29 notification-ar
 1059 postgres   1   0  295772   8712   8552 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.08 postgres
  968 root       1   0  395980   8528   4812 S   0.0  0.2   0:01.71 snapd
 1760 rakib      1   0  236328   8228   7180 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.76 applet.py
 1438 rakib      1   0  396008   8192   7592 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.50 mate-session
 1259 whoopsie   1   0  374400   7820   7820 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.04 whoopsie
 1837 rakib      1   0  408840   7520   7496 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.06 mate-screensave
 2228 rakib      1   0  527412   7432   7224 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.36 gjs
 2269 rakib      1   0  190184   7416   3892 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.11 gvfsd-metadata
 1775 rakib      1   0  321612   7152   6912 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.07 polkit-mate-aut
 4063 rakib      1   0   24764   6864   3120 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.30 bash
 2034 root       1   0  347940   6792   6392 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.21 upowerd
 1071 root       1   0  274780   6156   6132 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.03 cups-browsed
 1866 rakib      1   0  404284   6012   6012 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.01 gvfs-afc-volume
 1105 root       1   0  175288   5968   5968 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.08 unattended-upgr
 1692 rakib      1   0  345840   5836   4476 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.72 ibus-daemon
  924 root       1   0  167124   5820   5572 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.69 thermald
 1787 root       1   0  366880   5060   4552 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.53 udisksd
 1759 rakib      1   0  285632   4940   4388 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 gvfs-udisks2-vo
 1099 root       1   0  282208   4856   4464 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.22 polkitd
 1730 rakib      1   0  206860   4852   4560 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.36 at-spi2-registr
  941 root       1   0  276328   4820   4256 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.26 accounts-daemon
 1940 rakib      1   0  150692   4736   4720 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 obexd
 1745 rakib      1   0  188704   4584   4268 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.67 ibus-engine-sim
  948 root       1   0   93520   4464   4308 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.01 cupsd
 1904 rakib      1 -11  435688   4464   3956 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.22 pulseaudio
 1078 root       1   0  350404   4412   3964 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 lightdm
 2102 rakib      1   0  362032   4408   4408 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.01 gvfsd-dnssd
 1696 rakib      1   0  274832   4368   4168 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 gvfsd
 1762 rakib      1   0  435840   4300   4300 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 deja-dup-monito
 1936 rakib      1   0  427060   4204   4204 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.02 gvfsd-network
 1738 rakib      1   0  179152   4180   3328 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.31 dconf-service
 1856 rakib      1   0  350888   4156   4156 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 gvfsd-trash
 1238 root       1   0  230300   4100   3852 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 lightdm
 1701 rakib      1   0  406860   3952   3952 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 gvfsd-fuse
 1723 rakib      1   0  338048   3948   3948 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 at-spi-bus-laun
  952 message+   1   0   44220   3800   2728 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.41 dbus-daemon
 1058 lp         1   0   81208   3740   3740 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 dbus
 1710 rakib      1   0  264604   3688   3688 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.03 ibus-dconf
  338 root       1   0   32128   3596   3452 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.31 systemd-journal
 1832 rakib      1   0  257844   3544   3544 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.01 gvfs-goa-volume
 1134 root       1   0   44032   3516   3320 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.31 wpa_supplicant
 4189 rakib      7   0   42140   3476   2916 R  12.5  0.1   0:00.03 top
 1872 rakib      1   0  272032   3456   3456 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.02 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
 1170 postgres   1   0  296208   3364   3200 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 postgres
 1845 rakib      1   0  259836   3144   3144 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.02 gvfs-mtp-volume
 1509 nobody     1   0   53148   3096   3000 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.24 dnsmasq
  925 root       1   0   32108   3076   3076 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.02 bluetoothd
 1435 rakib      1   0  205528   3072   2944 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 gnome-keyring-d
 1682 rakib      1   0   43476   2952   2304 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.45 dbus-daemon
 1728 rakib      1   0   43024   2896   2736 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.15 dbus-daemon
 1284 ntp        1   0  112100   2832   2632 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.29 ntpd
    1 root       1   0  185368   2632   2032 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.69 systemd
 1907 rtkit      1   1  183540   2564   2496 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.07 rtkit-daemon
 1167 postgres   1   0  295772   2480   2344 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 postgres
 1168 postgres   1   0  295772   2460   2344 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.09 postgres
 1169 postgres   1   0  295772   2420   2344 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 postgres
  944 root       1   0   29324   2408   2284 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.01 cron
  927 avahi      1   0   44932   2364   2308 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.08 avahi-daemon
  357 root       1   0   46812   2260   2208 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.36 systemd-udevd
  930 root       1   0   28628   2140   2040 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 systemd-logind
  963 syslog     1   0  256388   2100   2100 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.07 rsyslogd
 1421 rakib      1   0   45156   1984   1984 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 systemd
 1918 rakib      1   0   24760   1920   1920 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.20 bash
 1895 rakib      1   0   12844   1796   1792 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bamfdaemon-dbus
 4062 rakib      1   0   14868   1736   1584 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 gnome-pty-helpe
 1171 postgres   1   0  150356   1700   1512 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 postgres
  938 daemon     1   0   26040   1696   1696 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 atd
 1465 root       1   0   16120   1564   1564 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 dhclient
 1274 root       1   0   16252   1280   1280 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 agetty
  962 root       1   0    4392   1104   1104 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.17 acpid
 2039 rakib      1   0   22364    664    664 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.08 syndaemon
  951 root       1   0   10704    632    632 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 avahi-dnsconfd
 1424 rakib      1   0  210912    268      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 (sd-pam)
 1000 root       1   0   19468    124      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.27 irqbalance
 1678 rakib      1   0   11140     40      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ssh-agent
 1018 avahi      1   0   44780     28      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 avahi-daemon
    2 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
    4 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
    6 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-ev
    8 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
    9 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/0
   10 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:01.23 rcu_preempt
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
   12 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
   13 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
   15 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 ksoftirqd/1
   17 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kb
   18 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2
   19 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
   20 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/2
   22 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kb
   23 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3
   24 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
   25 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/3
   27 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kb
   29 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   30 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   31 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_kthre
   35 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 oom_reaper
   36 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback
   37 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 kcompactd0
   38 root       1  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khugepaged
  116 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
  117 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
  118 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 blkcg_punt_bio
  120 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 edac-poller
  121 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq
  122 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdogd
  123 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.86 kswapd0
  126 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 irq/122-aerdrv
  127 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 irq/122-PCIe BW
  128 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 irq/123-aerdrv
  129 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 irq/123-PCIe BW
  130 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nvme-wq
  131 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nvme-reset-wq
  132 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nvme-delete-wq
  133 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 irq/124-mei_me
  134 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.20 kworker/1:2-eve
  135 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.14 kworker/2:2-mm_
  137 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 qat_device_rese
  138 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 qat_pf2vf_resp_
  139 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 adf_vf_stop_wq
  142 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kstrp
  143 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 zswap1
  144 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 zswap1
  145 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kworker/u9:0-rb
  161 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 charger_manager
  207 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 acpi_thermal_pm
  211 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  212 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  213 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_0
  214 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  215 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_1
  216 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
  217 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_tmf_2
  220 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kworker/0:1H-kb
  221 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.20 kworker/u8:4-zs
  223 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 kworker/2:1H-kb
  226 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.28 kworker/3:1H-kb
  227 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 kworker/1:1H-kb
  264 root       1   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.18 jbd2/sda1-8
  265 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ext4-rsv-conver
  278 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ipv6_addrconf
  375 root       1 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 loop0
  376 root       1 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 loop1
  378 root       1 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 loop2
  478 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cryptd
  529 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kworker/2:3-eve
  545 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cfg80211
  551 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.76 irq/130-iwlwifi
  555 root       1 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u9:1-hc
  762 root       1 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 loop3
  765 root       1 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 loop4
 1681 rakib      1   0   43596      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-launch
 2004 root       1 -10       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 krfcommd
 2970 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0
 3052 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kworker/0:0-eve
 3131 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.27 kworker/u8:0-i9
 3423 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.15 kworker/u8:2-ev
 3857 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 kworker/0:2-eve
 4016 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 kworker/3:3-eve
 4017 root       1   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:4-eve
```

result for `df -h --type tmpfs` :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           386M  6.1M  380M   2% /run
tmpfs           1.9G   32M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           386M   40K  386M   1% /run/user/1000
```

and output for `cat /etc/fstab | grep -i swap` :

```
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=89fea68f-1f77-4988-a87d-d29cb372fd96 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

output for `grep -v '^#\|^$' /etc/sysctl.conf` :
`vm.nr_hugepages=1172`

output for `cat /proc/meminfo` :

```
MemTotal:        3948976 kB
MemFree:          378476 kB
MemAvailable:     444968 kB
Buffers:           26448 kB
Cached:           303048 kB
SwapCached:        70320 kB
Active:           452188 kB
Inactive:         344376 kB
Active(anon):     327628 kB
Inactive(anon):   208796 kB
Active(file):     124560 kB
Inactive(file):   135580 kB
Unevictable:       13116 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:        999420 kB
SwapFree:         546692 kB
Dirty:              1016 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        427388 kB
Mapped:           178116 kB
Shmem:             69352 kB
KReclaimable:      28220 kB
Slab:              86288 kB
SReclaimable:      28220 kB
SUnreclaim:        58068 kB
KernelStack:        8352 kB
PageTables:        30300 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1773780 kB
Committed_AS:    3383848 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       26516 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             1136 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:    1172
HugePages_Free:     1164
HugePages_Rsvd:       63
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:         2400256 kB
DirectMap4k:      243000 kB
DirectMap2M:     3866624 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

And I can't figure out where is the extra memory is used. And how can I solve this problem?
P.S. Thank you everyone for helping me out. The problem is solved

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102846/discussion-on-question-by-ton-frere-high-ram-usage-is-slowing-down-my-laptop).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the setting `vm.nr_hugepages=1172` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. This reserves 1172 * 2048 Kb = 2.4 Gb for huge pages, which are only used by certain applications. That is where most of your memory is allocated.

If you don't know the reason why this setting is there, I suggest you edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set it to 10 and reboot:

```
vm.nr_hugepages=10
```

It is likely that will fix your memory issues. With only 4Gb of RAM, it is very unlikely you need that number of huge pages.

Comment: Current value: [`sysctl vm.nr_hugepages`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/sysctl.8.html). `-w` to change it temporarly. `-a` to display all variables